# function takes too many arguments F#

Tags: f#

I have the following code. I explicitly defined the return type as `boolean`

```
let inputChecker (romanNumber:list<char>) :bool = function
   | [] -> false
   | head::tail when head<= tail.Head && tail.Head<=tail.Tail.Head  -> false 
   | _ -> true
```

but i think it consider the `:bool` as a parameter. I also tried `(:bool)`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use the function keyword? Maybe this can help you -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `function`, you don't specify the argument in the signature:

```
let inputChecker: (char list -> bool) = function
   | [] -> false
   | head::tail when head<= tail.Head && tail.Head<=tail.Tail.Head  -> false 
   | _ -> true
```

If you want to specify the argument explicitly, use `match`

```
let inputChecker (romanNumber: char list): bool = 
   match romanNumber with
   | [] -> false
   | head::tail when head<= tail.Head && tail.Head<=tail.Tail.Head  -> false 
   | _ -> true
```

Type annotations are not necessary, you can skip them.